# Javascript, Array to string format

Tags: javascript

I am in a situation in my Ionic project to convert array to string format(array). Here is the example

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

should be converted to

```
var strFruits = "['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango']";
```

I can do it using loop and string operation, but there should be an easy way to resolve this.

Comment: JSON.stringify maybe?

Comment: Yeah, why not JSON.stringify(fruits)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```js
const fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange'];
const format = "['" + fruits.join("', '") + "']";
console.log(format);
// => ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']
```

Or as suggested in the comments, using `JSON.stringify`:

```js
const fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange'];
const format = JSON.stringify(fruits);
console.log(format);
// => ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
```

I personally do not prefer the last one, because you are forced to use double quotes, and the only way to change that is using RegEx.

Comment: _“you are forced to use double quotes”_ — which would even make it valid JSON. Why would that ever be undesirable? Why would single quotes ever be preferrable to double quotes?

Comment: If your code style prefers to use single quotes, it's inconsistent to use double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can use either  use `JSON.stringify(fruits)` or  Just concat `"["+fruits.toString()+"]"`

Answer (score 1):

For

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

You could do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fruits));
// ["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango"]
```

This returns a string that can be parsed back to JS using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which seems to be exactly what you need

To the scope of your question, this would be valid too:

```
console.log(`['${fruits.join("', '")}']`);
// ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango']
```

This would return what you asked for with the single quotes, but using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has the added advantage that the resulting string can always be parsed back (I'ts always valid JSON)

```
JSON.parse(`['${fruits.join("', '")}']`);
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]).replace(/"/g, "'"))
```

But i think first variant with method "join()"  more suitable for this case, because replace() will work with wrong way, if text will contain double quotes.